# Firebase TestLab not waiting typing finish to take screenshot

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I'm using Espresso in my Instrumented Tests and Firebase to run them, and it is working just fine. But i think Firebase is screenshoting to early. With Spoon, this exactly behavior also happens.

```kotlin
ScreenShotter.takeScreenshot("main_screen_1", activityRule.activity)

isTextEqualsTo(R.id.toolbarTitle, R.string.add_book)

typeTextOnAEmptyEditText(R.id.titleInputText, title)
typeTextOnAEmptyEditText(R.id.descriptionInputText, description)

ScreenShotter.takeScreenshot("main_screen_2", activityRule.activity)
```

For above sample, i'm getting this as result:
[image]

Looking carefully, you can check that description label is going up, during material ui animation, meaning that Espresso has started clicking/typing.

I simply don't know what is going on here.

EDIT: I think it is a bug. It is impossible do capture screen before and after text typing, and only in text typing (`ViewActions.typeText`). I don't know yet if it is a bug in TextInputLayout (Material UI) or in the screen capture function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just found the reason.

It is a bug in InputTextLayout/TextInputEditText, don't know why or how. Just added a new simple EditText and then worked.
[image]

[Issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1287) oponed.

Lesson learned: If you want to audit a app flow during a ui test, don't use nothing from Material UI.